# Trying to combine all csv files in directory into one csv file

Tags: pandas, file, importerror

My directory structure is as follows:

```
>Pandas-Data-Science
   >Demo
   >SalesAnalysis
      >Sales_Data
         >Sales_April_2019.csv
         >Sales_August_2019.csv
         ....
         >Sales_December_2019.csv
```

So Demo is a new python file I made and I want to take all the csv files from `Sales_Data` and create one csv file in `Demo`.

I was able to make a csv file for any particular csv file from `Sales_Data`

```
df = pd.read_csv('./SalesAnalysis/Sales_Data/Sales_August_2019.csv')
```

So I figured if I just get the file name and iterate through it I can concatenate it all into an empty csv file:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(list())
df.to_csv('one_file.csv')

files = [f for f in os.listdir('./SalesAnalysis/Sales_Data')]

for f in files:
   current = pd.read_csv("./SalesAnalysis/Sales_Data/"+f)
```

So my thinking was that current will create a single csv file since `f` prints out the exact string required ie. `Sales_August_2019.csv`

However I get an error with `current` that says:  `No such file or directory: './SalesAnalysis/Sales_Data/Sales_April_2019.csv'`

when clearly I was able to make a csv file with the exact same string. So why does my code not work?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
os.path.expanduser("/mydir")

extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

#combine all files in the list
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])
#export to csv
combined_csv.to_csv( "combined_csv.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: for os.chdir("mydir") in the "mydir" part do I write "./SalesAnalysis/Sales_Data" ?

Comment: yes, the folder where you had store the csv files to merge

Comment: FileNotFoundError: './SalesAnalysis/Sales_Data

Comment: this is probably an error on your path. Check well you folder structure path

Comment: nope it works fine when i do something like df=pd_read_csv("filepath")

Comment: but when I try doing the iterating method it falls apart

Comment: try this:  `os.path.expanduser("/mydir")` replace old `os.chdir`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a problem with your current working directory not being what you expect. I prefer to do these operations with absolute path which makes it easier for debugging:

```py
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('./SalesAnalysis/Sales_Data').resolve()
current = [pd.read_csv(file) for file in path.glob('*.csv')]
demo = pd.concat(current)
```

You can set a breakpoint to find out what `path` is exactly.